# Scanning for Wifi networks on Android Things returns empty list

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I'm running Android Things on a Raspberry Pi 3 with a touch screen attached.

I am trying to create my own GUI in my app to connect to available wifi networks, using the WifiManager class. However, the `getScanResults()` function always returns an empty List, even when you can see wifi networks scanned in the IoT Launcher.

I know from the docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults())

> If there is a remote exception (e.g., either a communication problem with the system service or an exception within the framework) an empty list will be returned.

But everything seems to be working fine except this scan function. How can I scan for networks successfully?

My code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
Log.v(this.class.getSimpleName(), "scanResults.size() = " + scanResults.size()); //Prints "0"
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see any results from `wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();`

Comment: @NickFelker Yes, it returns a list of all the Wifi networks I have previously connected to (and of course the one I am currently connected to)

Comment: Can you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: It may be help to take a look at this app I built a while ago. It was meant for Android TV, and EAP Wi-Fi networks, but most of the code should be portable: https://github.com/ITVlab/Enterprise-Wi-Fi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wifi scan on Android is an asynchronous mechanism.

1. You first have to register for a specific intent: [SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION).
2. Then start scanning using: [startScan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startScan())
3. In the onReceive() method of your broadcast receiver you can call [getScanResults()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults())

You can find more information in the following post:  https://www.nplix.com/2017/03/12/scan-list-wifi-network-android/

Comment: @Terranology This was the correct solution. You need to register a broadcast receiver to listen for the above mentioned intent. It works the same way in Android Things as it does in regular Android

Comment: @Terranology as the name suggest, android things is based on android and uses the same principles and APIs (in most case). Feel free to give a better answer if you have one.